# JPA mapping @ManyToOne between Embeddable and EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have the following setup in my Spring Boot JPA application:

**Embeddable**

```
@Embeddable
public class LogSearchHistoryAttrPK {
    @Column(name = "SEARCH_HISTORY_ID")
    private Integer searchHistoryId;

    @Column(name = "ATTR", length = 50)
    private String attr;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private LogSearchHistory logSearchHistory;
    ...
}
```

**EmbeddedId**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_SEARCH_HISTORY_ATTR")
public class LogSearchHistoryAttr implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private LogSearchHistoryAttrPK primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "VALUE", length = 100)
    private String value;
    ...
}
```

**OneToMany**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_SEARCH_HISTORY")
public class LogSearchHistory implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "logSearchHistory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<LogSearchHistoryAttr> logSearchHistoryAttrs;
    ...
}
```

**Database DDLs**

```
CREATE TABLE log_search_history (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT log_search_history_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

CREATE TABLE log_search_history_attr (
    search_history_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    attr CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
    value CHARACTER VARYING(100),
    CONSTRAINT log_search_history_attr_pk PRIMARY KEY (search_history_id, attr),
    CONSTRAINT log_search_history_attr_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (search_history_id) REFERENCES
        log_search_history (id)
);
```

When I go to start the application, I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.foobar.entity.LogSearchHistoryAttr.logSearchHistory in com.foobar.entity.LogSearchHistory.logSearchHistoryAttrs

I am not sure why I am getting this error - the mapping looks correct (to me). What is wrong with this mapping that I have? Thanks!

Comment: where is `logSearchHistory` in `LogSearchHistoryAttr` ?

Comment: @Ramanlfc - it's in the EmbeddedId object. Should it be pulled out from there and put into `logSearchHistoryAttr`?

Comment: Manually add targetEntity to your OneToMany annotation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You moved the `mappedBy` attribute into an embeddable primary key, so the field is no longer named `logSearchHistory` but rather `primaryKey.logSearchHistory`. Change your mapped by entry:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.logSearchHistory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LogSearchHistoryAttr> logSearchHistoryAttrs;
```

Reference: [JPA / Hibernate OneToMany Mapping, using a composite PrimaryKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952141/jpa-hibernate-onetomany-mapping-using-a-composite-primarykey).

You also need to make the primary key class `LogSearchHistoryAttrPK` serializable.

Comment: Is it okay to leave the `@ManyToOne` mapping? I ask because I get the error: >ERROR: column logsearchh8_.id does not exist

Comment: It's still in there in my test.

Answer (score 2):

At **OneToMany** part:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.logSearchHistory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LogSearchHistoryAttr> logSearchHistoryAttrs;
```